# Can you do a comparison in a variable assignment in bash?

Tags: bash, comparison, variable-assignment, ternary-operator

In PHP, I can assign a variable like this:

```
$a = ($b == $c) ? $x : $y;
```

Which assigns to $a the value $x iff $b == $c, and $y otherwise.
Is there a way to do this natively in bash?

I am aware that it is possible using a conventional if statement, or using a subshell with echo, but I was hoping there might be a simple way to do it. Writing a 6-line if statement or using a subshell seems like a lot for such a basic operation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
[[ $b = $c ]] && a="$x" || a="$y"
```

Comment: It also seems to work with single [, any reason [[ is better?

Comment: the main advantage, in my view, is that `[` is more fragile regarding empty values when you don't quote variables. example: `b=5; c=; [[ $b != $c ]] && echo ok; [ $b != $c ] && echo ok`